# What is the max number of shortest paths between two fixed vertices in a complete graph？

Tags: graph-theory

There is a graph which is an undirected complete graph and the weights of the graph edge are always positive.
I select two vertices which are $a$ and $b$ respectively and the two vertices are set at the first time and are fixed points.

How can I  set the weight of the edges in order to let the number of shortest paths(between $a$ and $b$ and all shortest paths share the same distance) between $a$ and $b$ (two previously selected vertices) reaches the maximum？

Can I transform this problem into another problem which is related to combination so that I can solve this problems by using the knowledge of discrete mathematics or solve it by using the knowledge of graph theory？

Is there any algorithm that is suitable for my problem？

Comment: I bet the solution is the following: consider first a linear graph with any positive weights. Then saturate it by putting weight between x and y to the sum of weights of intermediate steps. This gives $2^{n-1}$ shortest paths in the new graph, between the two vertices which were extremities of the linear graph.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,this problem has been solved. But a more complex problem appears. Instead of considering one  vertex pair a and b, I now consider K vertex pairs which contain 2K vertices,so how to adjust the edge weight to maximize the sum of K vertex pair's number of shortest path？